# How to specify the type of Data being sent in URLRequest in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, networking

I am trying to understand how to specify the type of data sent in a URLRequest
using the `URLRequest.addvalue()` method in Swift.

For example I have learned that

`URLRequest.addValue("applications/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

specifies **json** data to be send. 
If for instance I need to send in xml, how should I go about that?

Any resources will also be helpful!

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)?

Comment: I was browsing the Apple documents and had a hard time finding it, but thanks for referring it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we can't assign header field to URLRequest class directly. So make a variable of URLRequest first.

```
// create post request
let url = URL(string: "http://www.myserver.com")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// set header field
request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

// insert xml data to the request
let stringParams : String = "<msg id=\"123123\" reqTime=\"123123\">" +
    "<params class=\"API\">" +
    "<param name=\"param1\">123213</param>" +
    "<param name=\"param2\">1232131</param>" +
    "</params>" +
"</msg>"
request.httpBody = stringParams.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)

// api call
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    // process with data
    print(data)
}
task.resume()
```